# UITextField can send its action twice. Is this an iOS bug, or did I make an error?

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitextfield

In iOS, I have a `UITextField` in a `UITableViewController` scene that is governed by a Navigation Controller.  All static cells.  The text field has the "Clear on editing" flag switched on.  I want to get and save the value entered in the field, so I have the `-editingDidEnd:` action call my `saveData:` method in the custom `UITableViewController` subclass.  If I click out of the text field, all is well. However, if I back out of the scene using the Back navigation button, then `saveData:` gets called twice.  Once with the entered value, and a second time with an empty value. This appears to be incorrect behavior.

I've made a demo project and posted it to GitHub here:  https://github.com/davehirsch/BugDemo

Am I doing something wrong?  Is this an iOS bug?  It seems unlikely that it's a bug nobody else has found (and I've looked around for others reporting similar things).  I'm running the latest non-beta versions of Xcode and OS X, and the bug is happening in the iOS Simulator (but I'm not sure if it would happen on a real device, I guess).

Comment: are you adding any notification for tracking of changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right. It looks like a bug in `UINavigationController`.

Before and after animation the method `[UITextField resignFirstResponder]` is called before and after animation. The first call is done by `[UINavigationController popViewControllerAnimated:]`, and the second one in `[UINavigationConteoller navigationTransitionView:didEndTransition:fromView:toView:]` that call `[UIView(Hierarchy) _removeFirstResponderFromSubtree]`.

Looks like your text field hasn't resigned yet as a first responder before animation ends.

### [EDIT]

I recommend to look at rdelmar comment.

Comment: You can get around this apparent bug by having the text field resign as firstResponder in viewWillDisappear.